# Better Guard (Spork/RSpec)

Tags: rspec, bundle, guard, spork

I'm using `bundle exec guard` as my main test runner, and I'm liking it even though I'm a total n00b about it.

Something that has troubled me is the way that I have to manually 'r' to restart it for any real code change. I'm OK with the slow reload time (though it'd be nice if it did something like what `rails c`'s `reload!` does), but the thing I can't stand is having to switch to the window manually and hit `r`.  Especially when I forget to do this, and think it's all good. So it is inconsistency on top of inefficiency.

Here is my Guardfile:

```rb
guard 'spork', wait: 45 do
  watch 'config/application.rb'
  watch 'config/environment.rb'
  watch %r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$}
  watch %r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$}
  watch 'Gemfile'
  watch 'Gemfile.lock'
  watch 'spec/spec_helper.rb' do 'spec' end
end

guard 'rspec', version: 2 do
  watch %r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$}
  watch %r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$} do |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" end

  watch %r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$}
  watch %r{^app/(.+)\.rb$} do |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$} do |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$} do |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$} do |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] end
  watch %r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$} do 'spec' end
  watch 'spec/spec_helper.rb' do "spec" end
  watch 'config/routes.rb' do 'spec/routing' end
  watch 'app/controllers/application_controller.rb' do 'spec/controllers' end
  # Capybara request specs
  watch %r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$} do |m| "spec/views/**/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^app/.*\.sass$} do 'spec/requests/*' end
end
```

I thought about doing something like:

```rb
watch %r{^app/models/*.rb} do system `killall bundle` end
…
```

But that's obviously an enormous kludge. Still it'd be better than seeing fakely-passing tests scroll by.

Thanks for any advice on making this setup better.

Comment: Aha, this one's way simple.

All you need to do is add more `watch` lines in that `guard 'spork'` section. Anything in there will restart the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "Day 1" edit (that is, the one above was me fumbling around trying
to get it going with as little learning as possible, but this one is a bit
more informed). This one is working much better for me.

```rb
notification :on
guard 'spork', wait: 45, rspec_env: { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  [
    %r{^config/(environments|initializers)/.+\.rb$},
    %r{^config/(application|environment|routes)\.rb$},
    %r{Gemfile(.lock)?},
    %r{^lib/},
    %r{app/(models|controllers)},
    'spec/spec_helper.rb'
  ].each do |e| watch e end
end
guard 'rspec', version: 2 do
  watch %r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$}
  watch %r{^app/(.+)\.rb$} do |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$} do |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$} do |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$} do |m| "spec/views/**/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" end
  watch %r{^app/.*\.sass$} do 'spec/requests/*' end
end
```

It's working OK. More improvements to come, I bet.
—☈